# Expectation of matrix product $H^TNH$

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose we have a matrix $H\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $H 1_n = 0_n$ and another matrix

$$\mathcal{N}=\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{n}&-\frac{1}{n}&\cdots&-\frac{1}{n} \\
-\frac{1}{n}&1-\frac{1}{n}&\cdots&-\frac{1}{n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
-\frac{1}{n}&-\frac{1}{n}&\cdots&1-\frac{1}{n}
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$

Why is the expectation the following?

$$\mathbb{E}\{H^T\mathcal{N}H\} = \left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) \mathbb{E}\{H^TH\}$$

How could I get the $1-\frac{1}{n}$?

The document I found shows that expectation of $\mathbb{E}\{H^T\mathcal{N}H\}$ should be $\mbox{tr} (\mathcal{N})\mathbb{E}\{H^TH\}$, if it is, this expectation should be $(n-1)\mathbb{E}\{H^TH\}$, I wonder if there is anything wrong.

Comment: You have $N = I-\frac 1n 1_n1_n^T$. Thus, $H^TNH = H^TH - \frac 1nH^T1_n1_n^TH$. So, the claim can not be true, since $E(H^TNH) = E(H^TH) - \frac 1n\cdot E((H^T1_n)(H^T1_n)^T)$ and $(H^T1_n)(H^T1_n)^T$ is always positive semi-definite, so the expectation is positive semi-definite, which implies $E(H^TNH)\le E(H^TH) < (n-1)E(H^TH)$ -- at least for $n\ge 3$.